# NoClassDefFoundError when I call RestTemplate.exchange() on a fake api

Tags: java, resttemplate, jackson-databind

I upgraded jackson-databind lib to 2.10.0.pr3 to overcome some Veracode vulnerabilities and now one of my tests is failing on calling `RestTemplate.exchange()` on a bad api.

The `RequestEntity` has a url of `http://localhost:9999/fake/api` and `HttpMethod = POST`. I have a custom dto for a response type.

```
getRestTemplate().exchange(requestEntity, MyResponseDto.class);
```

My test initially expected a `ResourceAccessException`, and this worked ok up to 2.9.10.

After upgrade, when I debug into the library code into `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute()` the call on line 733, `requestCallback.doWithRequest(request)` throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` and I cannot find any implementation of that method.

Is there some new setup required? Do I need to `implement` the `RequestCallback` in my code and write a concrete implementation of doExecute? I tried this with a simple logging, but it did not break there, and I think that would be a regression of the library if I needed to do this.

Comment: To update. I noticed that 2.10.0 of databind has a compile dependency on 2.10.0 of core and annotations. So I updated both of those libs as well, and now I get a `Found duplicate and different classes in [...]` issue when building.